# How to resolve timeout error while executing transactions in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to insert bulk data in to blockchain. For 11,000 records records the insert is happening without any fault. But if I try to insert more, Im getting the following error.

```
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Error executing chaincode: Failed to execute transaction (Timeout expired while executing transaction)
```

Im using fabric sdk. My fabric verion is 1.2. Can anybody say how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the timeout the timeout value. If this dont work, check the chaincode container logs.
[Nodejs SDK example](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#sendInstantiateProposal__anchor)

Comment: how or where can I 'Try to increase the timeout the timeout value'?